# "This October I will have been xxx yrs in this country"

Tags: grammar

I'm new so please excuse if I'm asking something that had been many times before. I'm a foreigner living in UK, who loves English language so I strive for perfect use every time.

Sometimes people ask me how long I have been in this country. I like to round the number of years to the month in which I came, which was October. Therefore if someone asked me today I would have said:

> I will have been 7 years in the country this October.

or if today was sometime in December I would have said

> Last October I have been 7 years in the country.

So simple question: are these forms correct? Or should I just do the simple *"I will be 7 years here this October"*?

Comment: I'd say "in this country 7 years" rather than "7 years in the country", but the verb tense is fine, whereas "I will be" is incorrect.

Comment: -1 Lacks research. Question is too simple: voting to close GR.

Comment: @meta: I don't think OP knows anything about research. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I will have been 7 years in the country this October"

...is fine, but I'd rejig it a bit, so:

> "I will have been in the country seven years this October".

For the second, you could say:

> "Last October was the start of my eighth year in the country".

Comment: No, you could say 'Last October was the start of my *eighth* year here' if that was the seventh anniversary of arrival.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Even if my maths was a bit skewiff, was the English usage correct? I thought that was what we were here to establish.

Comment: Yes, though I think *here* (or *there* as appropriate) sounds more natural: I thought that was what I had said. (And is that really the current spelling of *skew-whiff*? You learn something every day.)

Answer (score 5):

How about:

> This October, I will have been in the country for 7 years.

and

> As of last October, I had been in the country for 7 years.

Comment: This is the most natural-sounding rephrasing, except I'd make one tiny modification to the second one: "As of last October, I **have** been in the country for 7 years." (Because you presumably haven't left.)

Comment: Ah yes - in-advertant use of the pluperfect... well spotted!

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to decide between sounding natural and 'using perfect English', Tomasz.

Very few natives would give a response beyond "Seven years," Seven years or so," "About seven years," or "About seven years now."

Of course, logically, natives couldn't actually answer this particular question: it would have to be: "How long have you lived in Yorkshire?"

Comment: I think in the UK the most "natural" response, bearing in mind OP's wish to round to the nearest year, would be *"Seven years **come** October"*. Regardless of whether or not the *"I will have been"* and *"in this country"* components are present.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: or it will be seven years this October.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I really like the "come October" approach. I think I will stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

> So simple question: are these forms correct? Or should I just do the
>   simple "I will be 7 years here this October"?

They sound unnatural and make it obvious they are the words of someone for whom English is not their first language.

For your first sentence, I would say: In October, I will have been in this country for seven years.

For your second sentence, I would say: Since October, I have been in this country for seven years.

Those would be more natural ways to say those senstences.

Comment: Personally, I can't really see much difference, from the grammar point of view, between "I will have been 7 years in the country this October." and "In October, I will have been in this country for seven years" but I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For spoken English, the following are the shortest, clearest forms I can think of in a conversational response to the question `How long have you been in this country?`

> 7 years as of October.

Comment: I think you forgot about November :D

Comment: @MarkTO thanks, edit answer to make it one case instead of two.